# Sql query to get total number of students in a class

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT c.id as ID, c.class_name as CLASS, COUNT(e.student_id) AS STUDENT_COUNT 
FROM classes as c
LEFT JOIN enrollments as e on e.class_id = c.id
where c.teacher_id = 8 AND e.approved = 1
group by c.class_name;
```

What I try to do is to get all the classes and the number of students that have been approved in those classes. The sql query should return something like

```
ID            CLASS          STUDENT_COUNT
1             Math              0
2             Biology           2
3             Algebra           1
4             Literature        5
```

The problem is that because of e.approved = 1 i don't get any classes at all. Suggestions?

My schema is as follows

CLASSES table

```
id, teacher_id, class_name, grade
```

ENROLLMENTS table

```
id, class_id, student_id, approved
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your query to use the e.approved in the left join condition:

```
SELECT c.id as ID, c.class_name as CLASS, COUNT(e.student_id) AS STUDENT_COUNT 
FROM classes as c
LEFT JOIN enrollments as e on e.class_id = c.id 
AND  e.approved = 1
where c.teacher_id = 8 
group by c.class_name;
```